# Pagination and duplicate content

Tags: seo, php, pagination

I have an archive page that displays the number of articles published. Because there were so many, I ran a pagination script:

for `127.0.0.1/archive/2/?p=x&pp=y`

where `p` is the page number and `pp` is number of articles to display per page.

The pagination looks like this:

```
Prev  1  2  3  4 ... 12   NEXT
```

with each item linking to `p` like `<a href="?p=x">x</a>`.

I also have the items per page setter: 25 | 50 | 100 `(<a href="?pp=y">y</a>)`.

Now I have a PHP script that fixes `pp` into a session variable. But I am worried about duplicate content (since incrementing `pp` values will be inclusive) and also content not getting indexed because its not in the pagination link. so in the example above, pages 5-11 will not be indexed.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: [Same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25441405/1591669) on [so].

Comment: Don't forget to approve the answer, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Set a canonical link on each of your item pages (not pagination pages) and make sure all the item page URLs are registered in your *sitemap.xml*. Make sure this sitemap is defined in your *robots.txt*. Then, let crawlers do their job.

Comment: Canonical to what?

Comment: Say an item has url http://yoursite.com/products/article1.html, then you should use this url in your canonical. For more information: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en#2